# Overriding Content Security Policy directive "frame-ancestors"

Tags: response-headers

We have a response header set up in IIS to set the Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'" in order to prevent people from embedding our website into other websites/domains.

However, we now have one of our webpages that we actually want to allow to be embedded on a certain other domains.  I know that we can add these other domains to our setting in IIS, but we only want this to apply to a specific page, and doing this would mean that all pages in the website could be embedded in an iframe on these other domains.

I have added a response header to the page in question but when the page is viewed in developer tools there are now 2 Content Security Policy entries, and it still doesn not load.  It looks like the borwser is reading the first one that says only allow to embed in "self" and not getting to the second one that also allows the additional domain:

[Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvMHY.png)

1. Do browsers just read the first Content Security Policy header and ignore any that follow?
2. Is it possible to keep the header that sets "self" in IIS so that it is automatically sent out with every page, but override/update the hjeader on a specific page to append other domains to the allowed list?

Thanks